# Able to Authenticate user in Firebase but cannot store user data in Firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am able to Authenticate users in Firebase authentication but cannot store their data, as in first and last name in Firebase database. It might be an issue with the code that I wrote?

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: userEmail, password: userPassword) { (user, error) in

        if let error = error
        {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            self.showMessage(messageToDisplay: error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

           if let user = user {
            var databaseReference: DatabaseReference!
            databaseReference = Database.database().reference()

            let userDetails:[String:String] = ["firstName":firstName, "lastName":lastName]
            databaseReference.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(["userDetails":userDetails])
```

[screenshoot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npNf7.png)

[screenshoot of authenticated users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4u64t.png)

Comment: edit your question and provide code instead of images.

Comment: If you hardcode the value of `firstName`, does the problem persist? I.e. `let userDetails:[String:String] = ["firstName":"firstName", "lastName":"lastName"]`

Comment: Yes I still encounter the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the rules for your realtime database to this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```